# JTextfield, how to verify content in the getText() method

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have a textfield called x.

When the textfield contains " ", I want to do something. If it does not, do something else.

I tried doing

```
String test = x.getText();
if(test.startsWith(" ")){buttonN.setForeground(Color.GRAY));}
else{buttonN.setForeground(Color.BLACK));}
```

but it didnt work. any suggestions

Comment: Is that whitespace (tab, space, newline etc...) or just a space?

Comment: Try this instead. Just to make sure. Character.isSpaceChar(test.getChar(0))

Comment: Try if(test.startsWith("\\s"))

Comment: Are you sure it is not a problem with setForeground?

Comment: `didn't work` describes which phenomena exactly? Didn't compile, terminated the JVM, threw an exception, led to a wrong result (expected <-> found)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Color.GRAY)) and (Color.BLACK)) end with 2 closing parenthesis, while only one was opened.

```
String test = x.getText();
if (test.startsWith (" "))
{ 
     buttonN.setForeground (Color.GRAY); 
}
else buttonN.setForeground (Color.BLACK);
```

Some spaces around parenthesis make the reading more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `contains`?:

```
 if(x.getText().contains("\u0020"))
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
 else
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

Although the aforementioned will work, it won't detect **tabular spacing**. That being said, I'd recommend using a *regular expression* instead:

```
if(Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher(x.getText()).find())
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
else
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

[Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Why would you use the unicode value for the space? I hope you don't use "\u0060" when you search for an "a" (if thats what the unicode value is). You should not use magic numbers.

Comment: @camickr: WOW, would you feel better if I assigned the "magic number" to a variable ... `private static final String SPACE = "\u0020";`? Or better yet, if I had just used `" "`? Quit nitpicking ...

Comment: It is not nitpicking. Tthe person asking this question is obviously a beginner. Many beginners just use the presented suggestion word for word without understanding the importance of all the code. Your solution should encourage good programming techniques. Many people may know what unicode 20 represents, but I'm guessing far fewwer people know what \u0056 represents. The code you write should be self documenting. My suggestion was to use " ", which leaves know doubt about whay you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ensure if the text field is empty regardless of whether it contains space, tab, newline etc. use the following:

```
if(x.getText().trim().length() == 0){
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
}else{
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

The `String.trim()` removes any whitespace in the String.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for any verifycation of the `getText()` command is this:

```
If (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
} 
else {
    buttonN.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}
```